# position sticky on ios has margin in top

Tags: html, ios, css

i'm trying to do navbar with new position "sticky" and i did definition of sticky to avoid safari's issue but i faced another issue i found space between to border of page and navbar like that

[image]

and that my css code

```
.nav-heder {
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
top: 0;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
z-index: 5;
height: 60px;
padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.margin-bottom-sm { margin-bottom: 1em; }
.container{
    /* padding-top: 20px; */
}
```

this is html cose

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- header ,tools.back to ,title of page -->
    <div class="row margin-bottom-sm nav-heder">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 "><a href="#" class="webviewClose"><img src="./assets/images/arrow-left.png" srcset="./assets/images/arrow-left@3x.png 1000w"></a></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-md bold text-center"> Your Prizes </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-right bold"><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-right bold"><a href="#" id="address-book"><img src="./assets/images/contactscopy2.png" srcset="./assets/images/contactscopy2@3x.png 1000w"></a></div></div>
    </div>

    <!-- content of page -->
    <div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your html and any other css too? Also the picture doesn't make clear to me what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Webber I have added html code

Comment: This is still insufficient information. I copy pasted your code and it works fine: https://codepen.io/webbertakken/pen/xJpmvr. Looks like you put something before it.

Comment: @webber my code is working great on firefox ,chrome ,android  but on ios doesn't i will check is there thing before it

Comment: Does it have anything to do with that you're trying to hide an ad? or where does the ad come from in the first place?

Comment: I will try to explain; You are showing a screenshot with contents that are not in the provided code. I'm asking for extra code. In the meantime i'm trying to be helpful by creating a codepen in which your code seems to work perfectly fine. You haven't reported back on whether there is something before the div, you haven't provided the full code, and you haven't explained how the ad got there. It would be useful if you actually read my comments and directed your questions to the community. Please provide the required information.